# Drupal 7 - Redirect path alias to latest node

Tags: path, alias, rules

I'm having some trouble with this problem, users can add photos to my website, I created a custom node template to display all the photos.

But now I want that each time a new photo is added, the path /news/photos/ get's updated to that node.

I'm now using a module called 'Rules' which seems to work ok, but it can't handle some of the problems I'm having.

1. The site is multi lingual
2. When a photo is deleted, the path alias is deleted and so is my menu link

Does anybody can think of a solution that would suit my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to do the same thing.  Here is one solution, but not as easy as you might like:
http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/05/23/drupal-7-create-a-url-which-display-the-latest-node-of-a-specific-content-type/

Comment: Please include information from the link in your answer. If the link dies, your answer becomes useless.